# GNU Parallel as job queue processor

Tags: php, gnu-parallel

I have a worker.php file as below

```
<?php

$data = $argv[1];

//then some time consuming $data processing
```

and I run this as a poor man's job queue using gnu parallel

```
while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done < very_big_file_10GB.txt  | parallel -u php worker.php
```

which kind of works by forking 4 php processes when I am on 4 cpu machine.

But it still feels pretty synchronous to me because read LINE is still reading one line at a time.

Since it is 10GB file, I am wondering if somehow I can use parallel to read the same file in parallel by splitting it into n parts (where n = number of my cpus), that will make my import n times faster (ideally).

Comment: Look at `parallel --pipe` and `parallel --pipe-part`. Also, consider changing `worker.php` to look at and loop over multiple parameters so that a single invocation can process many parameters/lines - the reason is you currently pay the price of starting an entire new PHP interpreter for every single line of your file! If you make your `worker.php` able to process lots of lines, you can use `parallel -X` and get much better performance.

Comment: How long does it take to run a single job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do the `while` business:

```
parallel -u php worker.php :::: very_big_file_10GB.txt
```

`-u` Ungroup output. Only use this if you are not going to use the output, as output from different jobs may mix.

`::::` File input source. Equivalent to `-a`.

I think you will benefit from reading at least chapter 2 (Learn GNU Parallel in 15 minutes) of "GNU Parallel 2018". You can buy it at
http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html
or download it at: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

Comment: super, that did it like magic, can you please add little explanation for the novice, specially the ::::  & the -u part?